# GCP Load balancer w/ backend bucket returns "content-type: application/octet-stream" for .js and .css files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, content-type, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm transitioning to serverless and trying to server all html/jpeg/png/css/js files in a GCP storage bucket, fronted by a GCP external HTTP/HTTPS load balancer.

HTML and images are served as their expected content-type, but CSS and JS files show this:

```
content-type: application/octet-stream
```

For Chrome, this appears to be a big problem because it will refuse to load the CSS with this error:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:

I have to work around it with by changing my HTML from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

To this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Is there a way to have the GCP load balancer (or backend bucket) set the proper MIME type for JS and CSS files?

Comment: Set the content type for the object in Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata

Comment: Yep that works `gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/css" gs://mybucket/css/*.css`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the correct Content-Type using this gsutil command:

`gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/css" "gs://mybucket/**/*.css"`

The `/**/*` part will recursively check all files and folders in the bucket.